# Sequel gem: Handling invalid date values gracefully

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm a ruby noob and I'm trying to process some blog posts using Sequel and the data_objects adapter:

```
DB = Sequel.connect('do:mysql://user:pass@localhost/database')

db[posts_query].each do |post|
  puts post
end
```

But I get `Sequel::InvalidValue` exception, complaining about the date column:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb:202:in `local': ArgumentError: argument out of range (Sequel::InvalidValue)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb:202:in `make_time'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/time.rb:271:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:295:in `string_to_datetime'
```

I tried to catch the exception:

```
begin
  db[posts_query].each do |post|
      puts post
  end
rescue Sequel::InvalidValue => e
  puts e.inspect
end
```

but that doesn't help much.

How can I find out which row has the incorrect value?

Also, is there a way to do this iteration, such that I can catch the exception but continue to loop over the remaining rows?

**Update:**

I switched to the mysql2 adapter and now I can at least see the invalid date:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql2.rb:154:in `each': Mysql2::Error: Invalid date: 2008-04-00 00:00:15 (Sequel::DatabaseError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql2.rb:154:in `block in fetch_rows'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql2.rb:89:in `_execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/mysql_prepared_statements.rb:34:in `block in execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:236:in `block in synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:104:in `hold'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:236:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/mysql_prepared_statements.rb:34:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:778:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql2.rb:171:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql2.rb:140:in `fetch_rows'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.42.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:154:in `each'
    from wordpress_importer.rb:112:in `process'
    from wordpress_importer.rb:308:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I used Firefox and SQLiteManager add-on to edit the tables and fields until I no longer got any errors, there were about four problems.

Answer (score 3):

Can you post more of the backtrace?  You need to see what is calling `string_to_datetime`.

Also, I would recommend against using the do/mysql adapter unless you have specific needs that require it.  Use the mysql or mysql2 adapter instead.  If the error is being caused by bogus datetimes in your MySQL database, then you may want to use the mysql2 adapter or use the mysql adapter and set `DB.convert_invalid_date_time = nil`.

Comment: Thanks, switching to the mysql2 adapter helped. Added full backtrace.

Comment: File a bug with the mysql2 adapter, since it isn't able to handle the conversion correctly.  To work around the issue, use the mysql adapter with "DB.convert_invalid_date_time = nil"